# How to get threading to work?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Threading

Partial Public Class frmTermsOfUse
    Inherits Form

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        rtxtContent.Text = My.Resources.TermsOfUse
    End Sub

   Private Shared [exit] As Boolean = True

    Private Sub btnAccept_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        XMLSettings.WriteValue("ShowToU", (Not chkDontShowAgain.Checked).ToString())
        [exit] = False
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmTermsOfUse_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        lblToU.Left = (Me.Width \ 2) - (lblToU.Width / 2)
        Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf Wait20Sec)
        t.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Wait20Sec()
        For i As Integer = 19 To 0 Step -1
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            Try
                Me.Invoke(DirectCast(Sub() btnAccept.Text = "Accept (" & i & ")", MethodInvoker))
            Catch
            End Try
        Next

        Me.Invoke(DirectCast(Sub()
                                 btnAccept.Text = "Accept"
                                 btnAccept.Enabled = True

                             End Sub, MethodInvoker))
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDecline_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmTermsOfUse_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs)
        If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing AndAlso [exit] Then
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I don't get the countdown on the button to work.
Button is disabled when I launch the application and does nothing else.

How can I fix this?

Already thanks for the help

Comment: You are not doing anything when catching exceptions after the Me.Invoke. Perhaps check that first?

Comment: I created a new form and used your form_load and Wait20Sec method and it worked perfectly. I saw the count down and it enables after 20 seconds. I would guess you have something else going on that is counter-acting the code you have here.

Comment: There's just no point in writing code like this and risk the FUD of using threads.  Use a plain Timer instead, the one you can find back in the toolbox.

Comment: And Hans why do I need it fud?